# Pandas - Check if row contain specific string and return result in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+----------------------+
|               A                   |    B       |   C                  |
+-----------------------------------+------------+----------------------+
| Joseph M. Acaba                   | 2004       |Geology               |
| Loren W. Act                                    Solar Physics         |
| James C. Adamson                  | 1984       |Aerospace Egineerig   |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

**i would like to check, for each row of column C, if there is the word “Engineering” or “Geology” in the respective phrase. I would like the result to be set in a new column** (“D”), as in the example below:

```
+----------------------+------------+----------------------+---------+
|               A      |    B       |   C                  | D       |
+----------------------+------------+----------------------+---------+
| Joseph M. Acaba      | 2004       |Geology               |True
| Loren W. Act         |             Solar Physics         |False
| James C. Adamson     | 1984       |Aerospace Egineerig   |True
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

I tried with :

```
check=pd['Undergraduate Major'].str.contains('Engineering'|”Geology”)
print(check)
```

and got the result:

```
0      False
1       True
2       True
3      False
4       True
       ...  
352     True
353    False
354    False
355     True
356    False
```

But I want the result to become a new column, with only “false” and “true”.

Comment: use pd['D']=pd['Undergraduate Major'].str.contains('Engineering'|”Geology”)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dataframe is named `df`, do:

```py
df['NewColumnName'] = df['Undergraduate Major'].str.contains('Engineering|Geology')
```

I would recommend avoiding using `pd` as the name of the dataframe because it's generally used for pandas, as in `import pandas as pd`.